# How to write a proper jump script at unity2d? rigidbody.addforce doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so i am creating a simple platformer and i am struggling to make player game object jump.
The problem is, when i press space, my gameobject just teleports up and then falls down and it doesn't look like a jump at all. As i know, it is supposed to simulate an impulse and i should be able to see the object moving up but i dont.

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        rigidbody2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * 50f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

}
```

Also, I tried to copy code from a couple of tutorials where it worked just fine but it doesn't worked out for me.

Comment: Add velocity on the y-axis. `rigidbody2d.velocity =new vector2(rigidbody2d.velocity.x,jumpPower);`

Comment: @bolkay it still just teleports, but now there is a pause between the moment i press a key and the moment when it reacts.

Comment: Get rid of `Force.Impulse`.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html  I'm not sure what the mass of your player is but it could be making you "blast off"

Comment: Let's see a picture of your Inspector. Of course, try to play with the jumpPower variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @bolkay commented you could change rigidbody's velocity, however if you got problems with this i thing you should follow unity's suggestion and not modify it directly and maybe start manipulating velocity when you got more skills. docs for velocity:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

that said, jump with velocity:

```
rb.velocity=rb.velocity+transform.up*jumpPower; //easier to predict
rb.velocity= transform.velocity*transform.up*jumpPower
rb.velocity= new vector2(rigidbody2d.velocity.x,jumpPower);//erases your rb's previous y velocity
```

I think your problem is in force you are applying(the code seems ok) try to declare a float and play with its value at runtime. Also check your rb's propreties in inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this solution:

```
rigidbody2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * 50f, ForceMode2D.Force);
```

I changed the `ForceMode2D.Impulse` to `ForceMode2D.Force`, maybe it will work. I met this problem too --  fly up and cannot get down XD